# Mongo Licensing (AGPLv3)

Tags: licensing, mongodb, agpl

I'm going to include MongoDb(AGPLv3) in my product. My product is SaaS, I don't install this to client directly. My software is ASP.NET MVC website. But MongoDb's drivers for .Net is under Apache
My questions are:

1) Should I license my software under AGPLv3 license if I use Mongo? I use them across drivers which written on Apache, but somewhere I've heard that if use GPL component in your software you must license whole your product under GPL

2) If I license my website under AGPLv3 should I provide code for all customers?

Thank you for answers?

Comment: You've read the licensing page? http://www.mongodb.org/about/licensing/

Answer (score 2):

If your product enhances the MongoDb *database server* in any way, then you must release your software under AGPL (or you must get a commercial license).
If your product just uses the MongoDb to store data in, then only the license terms for the MongoDB *drivers* are relevant and you can chose any license that is compatible with the Apache 2.0 license (which is just about any possible license).

If you choose to license your software under AGPLv3, then you are required to make the sources available to anyone that can use your services.